# Use a gradient as base color (like beamer@blendedblue)?

Tags: beamer, themes

I was asked to use two colors in a presentation. If it was only one color I would use beamer@blendedblue as base color, but since I need two colors, I can't use this. Is there a way to change the base color to a gradient?

Comment: What do you mean with basecolor? Can you make a MWE?

Comment: @samcarter I said "base color" no "basecolor" and it is what it says. For example, in the Berlin theme, the base color is blue, so all elements have some shade of blue... to black.

Comment: Ah, your talking about the `structure` colour. There is no global option to replace this colour with a gradient - which would be quite difficult, as it is used in so many places, for example also for font colours etc. But what would be possible to have specific elements of the frames with gradients, for example the frametitle. Easiest: just use a theme which already has a gradient for the frametitle. Can you draw a sketch which elements should have this gradient?

Comment: Example how to use gradients for some frame elements: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/311814/how-do-i-gradient-shade-the-background-of-a-beamer-section-subsection-in-head-fo/311829#311829

Comment: @samcarter yes, I saw that one, but the theme wasn't playing ball.

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned the `Berlin` theme in your comment. In my opinion this theme would not do well with gradients, as it lives from it's solid colour elements placed next to each other. Why not simply use your 2 colours for these elements? An example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\colorlet{color1}{green!60!blue}
\colorlet{color2}{blue}


\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=color1}
\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{bg=structure.fg!50!color2}
\setbeamercolor{subsection in head/foot}{bg=structure.fg!75!color2}
\usetheme{Berlin}

\title{title}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\section{bla}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{title}
    abc
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Well, this is another option through considering the colors (strong red and a very dark green) I guess I would have to run with it.