# beamer: find RGB definition of default (structure) color?

Tags: beamer

I would like to find the RGB definition of the default colour `structure` used in the default beamer theme.

For some specific themes like [crane](http://mirror.utexas.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/base/themes/color/beamercolorthemecrane.sty), I see that the code defines the color like `\definecolor{craneorange}{RGB}{252,187,6}`. Many themes (like [whale](http://mirror.utexas.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/base/themes/color/beamercolorthemewhale.sty)) refer simply to a `structure` colour. However, the [structure colour theme](http://mirror.utexas.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/base/themes/color/beamercolorthemestructure.sty) does not seem to give a RGB definition of what this structure color is? it only refers to `structure`, but I did not find where that `structure` was defined?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\definecolor{beamer@blendedblue}{rgb}{0.2,0.2,0.7} % use structure theme to change
```

Comment: I just used your answer here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/374598/. Can you explain how you found the solution?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Something I learned while trying to understand a question on this site, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/364495/36296

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner To find it, look into `beamercolorthemedefault.sty`.

Comment: Perfect -- I will add it to the other answer.