# beamercolorbox in the color of a theme

Tags: beamer

I'd like to have a `beamercolorbox` in the color of the theme "Madrid" (the color of the title box).
Currently, I approximated the color on myself.

```
\usetheme{Madrid} 
\setbeamercolor{bgcolor}{fg=white,bg=blue!75!black} 
\begin{frame} 
   \begin{beamercolorbox}[rounded=true,center=true]{bgcolor} 
      {\LARGE Text}   
   \end{beamercolorbox} 
\end{frame}
```

Comment: Is your problem solved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am not an expert -- I just investigated out of curiosity!

### Short Answer

Use the color pre-defined `structure` or the solution that [samcarter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/36296/samcarter) provides.

### Long Answer

- I found the style file `beamerthemeMadrid.sty` in the path `C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\beamer\themes\theme`.
- Two color themes are loaded, `\usecolortheme{whale}` and `\usecolortheme{orchid}`.
- `beamercolorthemewhale.sty` I found in the path `C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\beamer\themes\color`. `beamercolorthemeorchid.sty` too.
- Here are the color definitions I found in the two color theme files:

### `beamercolorthemewhale.sty`

```
\setbeamercolor*{palette primary}{use=structure,fg=white,bg=structure.fg}
\setbeamercolor*{palette secondary}{use=structure,fg=white,bg=structure.fg!75!black}
\setbeamercolor*{palette tertiary}{use=structure,fg=white,bg=structure.fg!50!black}
\setbeamercolor*{palette quaternary}{fg=white,bg=black}

\setbeamercolor*{sidebar}{use=structure,bg=structure.fg}

\setbeamercolor*{palette sidebar primary}{use=structure,fg=structure.fg!10}
\setbeamercolor*{palette sidebar secondary}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor*{palette sidebar tertiary}{use=structure,fg=structure.fg!50}
\setbeamercolor*{palette sidebar quaternary}{fg=white}
```

### `beamercolorthemeorchid.sty`

```
\setbeamercolor{block body}{parent=normal text,use=block title,bg=block title.bg!10!bg}
\setbeamercolor{block body alerted}{parent=normal text,use=block title alerted,bg=block title alerted.bg!10!bg}
\setbeamercolor{block body example}{parent=normal text,use=block title example,bg=block title example.bg!10!bg}
```

### Solved Questions

- I do not know where the color for `structure` is defined. Maybe there is some kind of default color theme....but then...see below.
- According to [beamer: find RGB definition of default (structure) color?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/371339), the default structure color is `\definecolor{beamer@blendedblue}{rgb}{0.2,0.2,0.7}`.
- This can be found in `beamercolorthemedefault.sty` (`C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\beamer\themes\color`) (thanks user [samcarter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/36296/samcarter)).
- This leads to `{RGB}{0.2*255,0.2*255,0.7*255} = {RGB}{51,51,178}` (actually `178.5`).

### Manuel Approach

- Here I just determine the color by using a simple so-called **color picker** This may be a designated software tool or a functionality of a decent graphic software. I used PowerPoint :).

[image]

### MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Madrid}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Test}
\begin{block}{Test}
Test
\end{block}
Test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe rename "Open Questions" to "Solved Questions" :)

Comment: @samcarter Done :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want the `beamercolorbox` to have the colour of the frametitle, use the colour of the frametitle :)

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Madrid} 

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test} 
   \begin{beamercolorbox}{frametitle} 
      {\LARGE Text}   
   \end{beamercolorbox} 

   \begin{beamercolorbox}{title} 
      {\LARGE Text}   
   \end{beamercolorbox} 
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[the colour of the title from titlepage works the same way - I was not sure which title box you are referring to]