# Tweaking infolines outer theme with horizontal shading

Tags: beamer, horizontal-alignment, themes

I'm trying to improve on the `infolines` outer theme by adding shading at the edge of each box of the footline. Taking a very simple example, my code is:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

% use shading packages
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings}

\useoutertheme{infolines} %current section at the top; author, institution, title, date and page at bottom

% define shading
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{
    \usebeamercolor{author in head/foot}
    \usebeamercolor{institute in head/foot}

    \pgfdeclarehorizontalshading{beamer@authorinstituteshade}{2.25ex}{%
        color(10em)=(author in head/foot.bg);
        color(18em)=(institute in head/foot.bg)
    }
}

% Adjust footline (use just author/institution/date/page)
\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{
\leavevmode%
\hbox{%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
        \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor
        \pgfuseshading{beamer@authorinstituteshade}%
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{institute in head/foot}%
        \usebeamerfont{institute in head/foot}\insertshortinstitute
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{date in head/foot}%
        \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\insertshortdate{}\hspace*{2em}
        \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{2ex} 
\end{beamercolorbox}}%
\vskip0pt%
}
\makeatother

\usecolortheme{beaver}
\setbeamercolor{author in head/foot}{bg=red!60!black,fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{institute in head/foot}{bg=red!40!,fg=black}

\usefonttheme{structuresmallcapsserif}

\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\institute{Institute}
\date{Date}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

And the output looks like this:
[image]
My color choices here are deliberately ugly, to make things more apparent. In practice, what I want is a "blend" feeling at the shared border of the red and pink areas in the footline; same for the pink and grey ones. So, I have the following three problems:

-why is the shaded area not vertically aligned with the box I put it in?

-how can I shift it leftwards to adjust it to the rim of the boxes?

-in the definition of the shading, here:

```
\pgfdeclarehorizontalshading{beamer@authorinstituteshade}{2.25ex}{%
        color(10em)=(author in head/foot.bg);
        color(18em)=(institute in head/foot.bg)
}
```

How can I set the height of the shading to automatically match the height of the box it is called in, instead of being manually set to the same height {2.25ex} ?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe use a single shading instead?

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings}

\useoutertheme{infolines} 
\usecolortheme{beaver}

\setbeamercolor{author in head/foot}{parent=palette primary,bg=,fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{title in head/foot}{parent=palette secondary,bg=,fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{date in head/foot}{parent=palette tertiary,bg=,fg=black}
\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{parent=palette primary,bg=}
\setbeamercolor{subsection in head/foot}{parent=palette secondary,bg=}

\colorlet{titleleft}{red!60!black}
\colorlet{titlemiddle}{red!40!}
\colorlet{titleright}{gray!40}

\pgfdeclarehorizontalshading[titleleft,titlemiddle,titleright]      {beamer@frametitleshade}{\paperheight}{%
    color(0\paperwidth)=(titleleft);
    color(0.15\paperwidth)=(titleleft);
  color(0.5\paperwidth)=(titlemiddle);
  color(0.85\paperwidth)=(titleright);
  color(\paperwidth)=(titleright)
}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{
    \leavevmode%
    \setbox\beamer@tempbox=\hbox{%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
            \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor\expandafter\beamer@ifempty\expandafter{\beamer@shortinstitute}{}{~~(\insertshortinstitute)}
        \end{beamercolorbox}%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
            \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
        \end{beamercolorbox}%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{date in head/foot}%
            \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\insertshortdate{}\hspace*{2em}
            \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{2ex} 
        \end{beamercolorbox}%
        }%
        \vskip-\beamer@tempdim%
        \beamer@tempdim=\ht\beamer@tempbox%
        \advance\beamer@tempdim by 4pt%
        \begin{pgfpicture}{0pt}{0pt}{\paperwidth}{20pt}
            \pgfpathrectangle{\pgfpointorigin}{\pgfpoint{\paperwidth}{\beamer@tempdim}}
            \pgfusepath{clip}
            \pgftext[left,base]{\pgfuseshading{beamer@frametitleshade}}
        \end{pgfpicture}
        \vskip-\beamer@tempdim%
        \box\beamer@tempbox%    
}%

\setbeamertemplate{headline}
{
    \leavevmode%
    \setbox\beamer@tempbox=\hbox{%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.65ex,dp=1.5ex,right]{section in head/foot}%
            \usebeamerfont{section in head/foot}\insertsectionhead\hspace*{2ex}
        \end{beamercolorbox}%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.65ex,dp=1.5ex,left]{subsection in head/foot}%
            \usebeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}\hspace*{2ex}\insertsubsectionhead
        \end{beamercolorbox}%
        }%
        \beamer@tempdim=\ht\beamer@tempbox%
        \advance\beamer@tempdim by 4pt%
        \vskip-\beamer@tempdim%
        \begin{pgfpicture}{0pt}{0pt}{\paperwidth}{20pt}
            \pgfpathrectangle{\pgfpointorigin}{\pgfpoint{\paperwidth}{\beamer@tempdim}}
            \pgfusepath{clip}
            \pgftext[left,base]{\pgfuseshading{beamer@frametitleshade}}
        \end{pgfpicture}
        \vskip-\beamer@tempdim%
        \box\beamer@tempbox%    
        \vskip0pt%
}
\makeatother


\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\institute{Institute}
\date{Date}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

(based on https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/311829/36296 )

Comment: Thanks, that's great! One issue though: why is there a blank space between the navigation bar and the footline?

Comment: @Magean fixed :)

Comment: Thanks again! Last (very minor) problem: there's a thin blank space to the left of the footline and headline. Can it be filled in? I tried adjusting the positioning of the various boxes but I'm too awkward at it. Also, could you please detail what you did with this chunk of code? I tried understanding it piecewise but I'm not expert enough... I have in mind the part that starts with
    \vskip-\beamer@tempdim%
and ends with:
        \box\beamer@tempbox%

Comment: @Magean Sorry, but I don't see a blank space. How are you compiling?

Comment: it's weird, the blank space only appears on some zoom percentages, but not all. Here's a zoomed-out example: http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2017/44/3/1509556516-capture-d-ecran-2017-11-01-a-18-14-55.png
It also appears on zoom-in documents, the relationship between the zoom % and the blank space is non-monotonic. I didn't observe it before, on basic infoline.
I'm compiling with Mactex, using TexStudio as GUI. Maybe I should update Mactex and see what happens.

Comment: @Magean My guess would be that this is a viewer artefact.

Comment: I guess so, it disappears upon scrolling. Anyway. Now I'm trying to use that shading after having designed a new color and applied it to all palettes. Now, it seems these settings take precedence over the shading, which doesn't work at all. I simply get plain infoline-style bars. The odd thing is, if instead of my color I copy beaver's code, I get the same problem. But, if I just call /usecolortheme{beaver} (as in the example), it works fine. A workaround is to create empty-colored boxes in the footline, then the shading works. It's not very clean however.

Comment: @Magean If you look at my code, I use empty coloured boxes and have the shading behind them.

Comment: Woops my bad, I focused on understanding the complex part of your code and forgot to check for the easy one at the top.